# Getting Database details form database.php page in Codeigniter

Tags: php, database, codeigniter-2

How can i get value from database.php page?
I mean we can access base url by using `base_url()`.The base url set in config.php page like this :

```
$config['base_url'] = 'example.com';
```

The database details in database.php is like:

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'username';
$db['default']['password'] = 'password';
$db['default']['database'] = 'database_name';
```

I want to access the this details in my controller page.How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
include('database.php');
echo $db['default']['hostname'];
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is another way that would work: you make the db settings available as config data.

You can do that by appending the following lines to the database.php file and use the filtering of your choice:

```
// get all configurations
$config = $db;

// be more specific
foreach($db as $key => $settings)
{
    $config[$key]['hostname'] = $settings['hostname'];
    // etc
}
```

Then you can load the data as you normally would load config values:

```
$this->load->config('database',TRUE);
$db = $this->config->item('default','database');
echo $db['hostname'];
// etc
```